# Unity launcher is missing

Tags: 11.10, unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

what happened to my dock in ubuntu? 11.10 i logged out because compiz fusion icon wasnt working then when i logged on again my dock wasnt there on the left side??? and there is no logout thing on the bar on the top right. later i got online from the 'help from ubuntu online' link then i tryed downloading google chrome which i should have. then it said that i was hacked by code or something????!!!
HELP!!!!!!

Comment: Hacked by code?.. wtf? what were you doing before that happened?.

Comment: It would help us to help you, if you were more specific about what exactly you did before this happened, what exactly happened (the exact words of the message) and it does not help to use all capital letters or more then one exclamation marks...

Comment: Calm down and rewrite your question. They're probably unrelated things; resetting Unity with the unity --reset command will probably fix the issue. The warning about you being hacked, is probably an attempt at fooling Windows users into installing a backdoor. The web is full of things like that. It's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

open terminal type

`unity --reset`

and it will reset your Unity shell the panel and the launcher(you are calling it a dock)
and Hacked?? this is Linux mate!!

Comment: Linux is very safe compared to other systems, but it isn't unhackable, as was proven when Linux' own development site, kernel.org, was recently hacked.

Comment: but that was done my top coders, not everyone can do that, so it leaves us 0.0001 probability of being hacked

Comment: No, that's simply not true. Once a security hole has been discovered, people write scripts to automate the task. Then it's as easy as running a program. No coding necessary at all. This is why it's so very important to install security updates as quickly as possible. Always.